# Почему при перемещении дёргается canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-canvas

Подскажите пожалуйста почему у меня дёргается `canvas` когда я его передвигаю?

[image: Скриншот]

Вот моё видео - https://yadi.sk/i/fxguWxWyq5WrL, лучше всего видно с 30 секунды

Вот мой XAML :

P.S. `ScaleTransform` может изменятся!

```
<Grid Name="window">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="canvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseMove="canvas_PreviewMouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="canvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" ContextMenuOpening="canvas_ContextMenuOpening" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="canvas_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" PreviewKeyDown="canvas_PreviewKeyDown" KeyDown="canvas_KeyDown" Background="#FFE9E9E9" PreviewMouseWheel="canvas_PreviewMouseWheel" Width="362" Height="195" Margin="312,176,302,207" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" MouseWheel="canvas_MouseWheel" PreviewMouseDown="canvas_PreviewMouseDown" PreviewMouseUp="canvas_PreviewMouseUp">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

Вот события Canvas-а :

```
        private void canvas_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                mousemovepressed = true;
                Mouse.Capture(canvas);
                p = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
            }
        }

        private void canvas_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            {
                mousemovepressed = false;
            }

        }

        private void canvas_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mousemovepressed == true)
            {
                    canvas.Margin = new Thickness(e.GetPosition(canvas).X-p.X, e.GetPosition(canvas).Y-p.Y, 0, 0);
            }
        }
```

UPD :

[image]

Comment: Если убрать ScaleTransform, то все норм будет )

Comment: Не, zoom должен быть

Comment: Если не секрет, опишите для чего вам это нужно? Скорее всего есть иные способы решения поставленной задачи, чем то, что вы  накодили.

Comment: Я хочу сделать что-то типа Pan and zoom canvas'а, если что в canvas лежат user control и поверхность должна быть бесконечной, ну то есть чтобы можно было сколько захочешь дёргать поверхность  (canvas)

Comment: Не уверен что я понял правильно. То есть вы хотите, чтобы был экран с содержимым, а canvas это как бы окошко видимости содержимого на  уменьшенной карте?

Comment: Не, наоборот canvas должен быть с содержимым, область видимости мне не нужна

Comment: Ну вот как в blueprint от ue4 рабочая поверхность например, чтоб вы сразу поняли.

Comment: там же 3D. Вы хотите сделать псевдо 3D?

Comment: Не, я не делаю игру :) Я хочу сделать canvas на подобии как в blueprint, а точнее pan и zoom. Тему сейчас обновлю

Comment: Ну то есть чтобы мышкой можно было перемещаться а колёсиком приближать и отделять)

Comment: Вы изначально выбрали сложную реализацию. И не правильную на мой взгляд. Смотрите в сторону ViewBox. Все что находится внутри этого элемента управления легко можно масштабировать. Или Viewport3D. Наверное, второе будет более предпочтительно. А задавать позиционирование через Margin - это вообще порочная практика. Это свойство можно использовать для изменения величины внешних границ разве что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что получилось. Посмотрите, изучите, если надо, задавайте вопросы )

Окно

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
        PreviewMouseWheel="OnPreviewMouseWheel" PreviewMouseDown="Window_PreviewMouseDown" PreviewMouseUp="Window_PreviewMouseUp"
        PreviewMouseMove="Window_PreviewMouseMove">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="canv">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Scale}" ScaleY="{Binding Scale}"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding CameraX}" Y="{Binding CameraY}"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Label Content="Some Element 1" Canvas.Top="-100" Canvas.Left="-100"/>
            <Label Content="Some Element 1" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="-100"/>
            <Label Content="Some Element 1" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="100"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

а вот код

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        WorkGround _source;
        bool _cameraPosChanging = false;
        Point _currentCursorPos;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            _source = new WorkGround
            {
                Scale = 1,
                CameraX=0,
                CameraY=0
            };

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public WorkGround Source
        {
            get
            {
                return _source;
            }

            set
            {
                _source = value;
            }
        }

        void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            Source.ChangeScale(0.1 * (e.Delta > 0 ? 1 : -1));
        }

        void Window_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                CaptureMouse();
                _cameraPosChanging = true;
                _currentCursorPos = e.GetPosition((FrameworkElement)sender);
            }
        }

        void Window_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            {
                ReleaseMouseCapture();
                _cameraPosChanging = false;
            }
        }

        private void Window_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_cameraPosChanging)
            {
                var currentCursorPos = e.GetPosition((FrameworkElement)sender);
                Source.ChangeCameraPosition(currentCursorPos.X - _currentCursorPos.X, currentCursorPos.Y - _currentCursorPos.Y);
                _currentCursorPos = currentCursorPos;
            }
        }
    }

    public class WorkGround : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        double _scale;
        double _cameraX;
        double _cameraY;

        public void ChangeScale(double delta)
        {
            Scale += delta;
        }

        public void ChangeCameraPosition(double deltaX, double deltaY)
        {
            CameraX += deltaX;
            CameraY += deltaY;
        }

        public double Scale
        {
            get
            {
                return _scale;
            }

            set
            {
                _scale = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Scale));
            }
        }

        public double CameraX
        {
            get
            {
                return _cameraX;
            }

            set
            {
                _cameraX = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CameraX));
            }
        }

        public double CameraY
        {
            get
            {
                return _cameraY;
            }

            set
            {
                _cameraY = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CameraY));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Если ваша версия студии ниже 2015, то, возможно, будут ошибки компиляции. Но их легко подправить.

Comment: По кайфу у меня как раз 2015, домой прийду проверю :D

Comment: Огромное спасибо, всё работает как планировалось :)))
А от куда вы это всё знаете, то есть из какой книги узнавали?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, не знаю, как ответить на ваш вопрос... не читаю я книг. )